# CSS Background inner shadow not fill full background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do inner shadow for my background picture. The picture is just pattern for repeat.

For shadow i made a code:

```css
background: #202020 url(images/img01.jpg) repeat;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 200px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 200px #000;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 200px #000;
```

When the content is fitted to browser (without scroll bar on the right side) everything is fine. But when some content of site is longer and you need to scroll page down then the background shadow is end (looks like cuted)

The question is how make inner shadow effect for full background even if there will be very long scroll bar.

Comment: are you giving shadow to div or body

Comment: it is shadow to body

Comment: your code is working fine i didt see any problem can you show your page

Answer (score 0):

change image with your image...

Enhance your code and than check and let me know..

```
 <div class='background'>
       This is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummyThis is dummy
</div>
 .background {
        background: #202020 url("http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/background-wallpapers-7.jpg") repeat;
       -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px 0 #f00;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px 0 #f00;
      width:100%;
      float:left;
      height:100%;
      padding:15px;
      color:#fff;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px 0 #f00;}
```

Hope this will work for you...

Comment: @user3422998

check this link.. its working here fine.. also updated latest code in my answe...

http://jsfiddle.net/gez0btoL/1/

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine

```
    <div>content</div>
```

css

```
     div{background:#fff url("images/img01") repeat;
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 200px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 200px #000;
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 200px #000;
     /*if you need word wrap
     word-wrap:break-word;*/
     }
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k8f65n60/)